# A function whose graph has vertical asymptotes at $x=+2$ and $x=-2$, and a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, asymptotics

Determine a function whose graph has vertical asymptotes at $x=+2$ and $x=-2$, and a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$?

I don't know to satisfy these conditions.

Comment: What does having vertical and horizontal asympotes mean? Think of appropriate denominator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(x+2)(x-2)}$$

Can you see why it works?

Comment: How did you get it?

Comment: @Rich If it has to have an vertical asymptote it means the the denominator vanishes at $x=2$ and $x=-2$. This is the simplest function that satisfies the requests. You can see that is also has an horizontal asymptote at $y=0$. If you wanted, say, and horizontal asymptote at $y=2$, this would not work. Can you see how to fix this function so that it has a astympote in $y=2$ instead of $y=0$? What the numerator would look like in this case=

Comment: I get it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are countless examples of such functions: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}c\cdot\tan^k\bigg(\dfrac\pi4x\bigg),\qquad x\in(-2,2)\\\\\dfrac a{(x+2)^n},~\qquad\qquad~ x<-2\\\\\dfrac b{(x-2)^p},~\qquad\qquad~ x~>~2\end{cases}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\begin{align}&a,b,c\in\mathbb R^*\\\\&k,n,p\in\mathbb N^*\end{align}$$